# webpack.config.ts with problems

Tags: angular

I was an error like that:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/app/.../page.component.html 1:0
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
>
> You may need appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> -> < div class="row" >
>
> < div class="card col-12 padd-left0 padd-right0" >
>
> < div class="card" >

I visited the site and searching for `webpack.config.ts` I found this:

[webpack3 jshint-loader does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273988/webpack3-jshint-loader-does-not-work/45274620#45274620)

I copy and past on my system and I got this error:

[image]

But if I delete this file, the error continues...

**EDIT**

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "admin-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.2",
    "@types/sweetalert": "^2.0.4",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.9.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.22.3",
    "angular2-busy": "^2.0.4",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.10.2",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.11",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.3",
    "cldr": "^4.14.0",
    "cldrjs": "^0.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "devexpress-reporting": "^18.2.10",
    "devextreme": "^18.2.10",
    "devextreme-angular": "^18.2.10",
    "extenso": "^2.0.1",
    "generic-validator": "^1.0.4",
    "globalize": "^1.4.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-maskmoney": "^3.0.2",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "knockout": "^3.5.0",
    "mydatepicker": "^2.6.6",
    "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
    "ng-treetable": "^1.3.3",
    "ng2": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^5.3.1",
    "ng2-data-table": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-drag-drop": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^3.5.0",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-sweetalert2": "0.0.8",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.3",
    "@angular/cli": "8.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "devextreme-intl": "^18.2.10",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Show me the `package.json` please

Comment: I ran this command `npm install webpack-cli -D` and the errors are gone, but the problem where I create a blockquote continues

Comment: please update the question and put the html of the page `page.component.html` I need to see if you have the structure of the html

Comment: use these commands `npm cache clear --force`
`rm -rf node_modules`
`npm install`

Comment: Remove-Item : Unable to find a parameter that matches the parameter name 'rf'. I have to execute like that: `rm node_modules -r -fo` and the problem continues

Comment: Inside of my ts, in @component({ }) it was `styleUrls: ['./page.component.html'],`, I changed to .css and problems are gone

Comment: You had a bad reference for that reason the unexpected token error appeared, but then your error was solved?

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO, yes, that's all I did

Comment: thanks for attention